# Java annotation cannot be found per reflection on a Kotlin data class

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, annotations

Given this Java annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotation
public @interface JsonProperty
```

and this Kotlin data class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class LossDocument(@JsonProperty("id") val id: String)
```

I would expect to find the annotation either here

```
LossDocument::class.java.declaredFields[0].annotations
```

or here

```
LossDocument::class.java.declaredMethods.first { it.name == "getId" }
```

but both have zero annotations. Is this a bug? Per [53843771](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843771), my impression is this should work. I'm using Kotlin 1.4.0.

When I declare the annotation explicitly as `@field:JsonProperty("id")` I can find it without problem using `LossDocument::class.java.declaredFields[1].annotations`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When you're annotating a property or a primary constructor parameter, there are multiple Java elements which are generated from the corresponding Kotlin element, and therefore multiple possible locations for the annotation in the generated Java bytecode.

> If you don't specify a use-site target, the target is chosen according to the @Target annotation of the annotation being used. If there are multiple applicable targets, the first applicable target from the following list is used:
> param, property, field. -- [Annotation Use-site Targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)

In your case the annotation is placed on the constructor parameter.

Comment: Hmm does this mean I have to check the constructor params? I will test this, didn't occur to me.

Comment: Looks like this is indeed the solution, thanks! I forgot that Jackson understands ctor parameter annotations as well. This is return want I want: `LossDocument::class.java.constructors[0].parameters[0].annotations`

Comment: This answer just saved me hours of frustration. I just couldn't figure out where my annotation has gone. Should have checked the bytecode... For those who might need it, kotlin Reflection offers an easy API for finding the primary constructor via `MyClass::class.primaryConstructor`.

Comment: If you want to control where the annotation is added in the byte code, you can prefix the annotation in your Kotlin code, as per the link given in the answer: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets